# Gradle Upload Fails But Still Deploys to Nexus

Tags: gradle, nexus

Hi my gradle build is failing in the `uploadArchives` task; but when I check Nexus, the WAR and POM are still deployed to nexus successfully.  Can anyone help me understand what's going on.

```
26-Jul-2016 18:46:28    :compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
26-Jul-2016 18:46:28    :buildProperties UP-TO-DATE
26-Jul-2016 18:46:28    :processResources UP-TO-DATE
26-Jul-2016 18:46:28    :classes UP-TO-DATE
26-Jul-2016 18:46:28    :compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
26-Jul-2016 18:46:28    :compileTestGroovy UP-TO-DATE
26-Jul-2016 18:46:28    :compileGsonViews UP-TO-DATE
26-Jul-2016 18:46:36    :war
26-Jul-2016 18:46:44    Could not transfer artifact com.company.software:app-name:war:16.7.26-RELEASE from/to remote (https://www.company.com/nexus/repository/maven-releases/): Failed to transfer file: https://www.company.com/nexus/repository/maven-releases/com/company/software/app-name/16.7.26-RELEASE/app-name-16.7.26-RELEASE.war. Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase: Repository does not allow updating assets: maven-releases.
26-Jul-2016 18:46:44    Could not transfer artifact com.company.software:app-name:pom:16.7.26-RELEASE from/to remote (https://www.company.com/nexus/repository/maven-releases/): Failed to transfer file: https://www.company.com/nexus/repository/maven-releases/com/company/software/app-name/16.7.26-RELEASE/app-name-16.7.26-RELEASE.pom. Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase: Repository does not allow updating assets: maven-releases.
26-Jul-2016 18:46:44    :uploadArchives FAILED
26-Jul-2016 18:46:44    
26-Jul-2016 18:46:44    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
26-Jul-2016 18:46:44    
26-Jul-2016 18:46:44    * What went wrong:
26-Jul-2016 18:46:44    Execution failed for task ':uploadArchives'.
26-Jul-2016 18:46:44    > Could not publish configuration 'archives'
26-Jul-2016 18:46:44       > Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.company.software:app-name:war:16.7.26-RELEASE from/to remote (https://www.company.com/nexus/repository/maven-releases/): Failed to transfer file: https://www.company.com/nexus/repository/maven-releases/com/company/software/app-name/16.7.26-RELEASE/app-name-16.7.26-RELEASE.war. Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase: Repository does not allow updating assets: maven-releases.
26-Jul-2016 18:46:44    
26-Jul-2016 18:46:44    * Try:
26-Jul-2016 18:46:44    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
26-Jul-2016 18:46:44    
26-Jul-2016 18:46:44    BUILD FAILED
26-Jul-2016 18:46:44    
26-Jul-2016 18:46:44    Total time: 27.993 secs
```

Comment: Please add the stacktrace by running with `--stacktrace` command line flag

Comment: Are you sure you are not trying to redeploy a release artifact that is already in the repository?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar error pushing a maven release to a hosted release repository:

```
Error code 400, Repository does not allow updating assets: Releases -> [Help 1]
```

To fix it (in nexus 3) I edited the repository and switched the "Deployment policy" value from "Disable redeploy" to "Allow redeploy"

My guess is that it allowed an initial deployment, but then failed to upload newer versions due to the policy.